# GridFS with location-based sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding, gridfs

Is there any way to shard the gridFS files and chunks based on a location information ?

I want to setup a mongo configuration with sharding and replication for handling multi-sites and guaranteeing that the data produced on one site remains accessible even if the sites are isolated.

I followed the following documentation from mongo and it works just perfectly for the standard collections but not for GridFS.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/

All I found for GridFS was _id based or file_id based sharding. 
By now the only solution I have would be to use different GridFS prefixes which means different collections and to shard them each on a given site.

I'm using :

- mogodb 3.2
- Java driver
- Python driver

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on StackExchange :
[How to define shardKey on GridFS collections to achieve Location/Data Centre affinity (MongoDB)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183027/how-to-define-shardkey-on-gridfs-collections-to-achieve-location-data-centre-aff/183055)

Given that the only possibility is to shard the chunks on the ID, the idea is to use `MongoGridFSCreateOptions` to force a location-based ID to the chunks.